# privliages that the View Setup and Configuration allow?

Tags: force.com, security

I'm looking into the user privilage: View Setup and Configuration. It allows a user to  View the App Setup and Administrative Settings pages.

I don't know which pages SF is referring to, or how to navigate to them.....

Comment: It's just the Setup page, what you get to when you click Setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to the pages they're referring to...

**For Standard Objects:**

`Setup->Customize->AppSetup->ObjectName(e.g. Opportunities)->PageLayouts-> Select: New, Edit, Del, or PageLayoutAssignments`

**For Custom Objects:**

`Setup->Create->Objects->ClickOn "Object's Label"->Scroll down to "PageLayouts"-> Select: New, Edit, Del, or PageLayoutAssignments`