# Invalid field Username on User : SOQL Query

Tags: soql, force.com, user, user-record

I simply cannot understand the reason why I am getting this below error.

```
17:16:15.106 (1106785435)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[29]|system.UserInfo.getUserId()
17:16:15.107 (1107062779)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[29]|System.QueryException: No such column 'Username' on entity 'User'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
17:16:15.107 (1107185681)|FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: No such column 'Username' on entity 'User'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Trigger.AuditUserTrigger: line 29, column 1
17:16:15.107 (1107198322)|FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: No such column 'Username' on entity 'User'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

I have got a before update trigger on User which is querying for the UserName field on the User object.

```
User user = [Select Id, Username From User u Where u.id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

I also receive an error in the logs whenever I open  the developer console.

```
14:05:11:380 FATAL_ERROR System.SObjectException: Invalid field ManagerId for User
```

Comment: The queries run fine in the Query Editor.

Comment: Post the complete logic atleast method.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly a permissions issue. The user performing the transaction doesn't have access to the User.Username field.

Does their Profile have the [View Setup and Configuration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/privliages-that-the-view-setup-and-configuration-allow) permission?

Are you dealing with a Communties / Partner Portal User?

One oddity from the [User](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) documentation:

> ## Usage
>
> Use this object to query information about users and to provision and modify users in your organization. Unlike other objects, the records in the User table represent actual users—not data owned by users. **Any user can query or describe User records**.