# System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: User.ProfileId

Tags: apex, user-record

I am trying to create a user as below,

```
User u = new User();
u.Username = userName;
u.Email = email;
u.firstName = firstName;
u.lastName = lastName;
u.CommunityNickname = communityNickname;
u.ProfileId = MyUtil.getProfileId();
```

but i am getting error at last line as below,

> System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: User.ProfileId

Answer (score 2):

This sounds very much like a permissions issue to me.

There are a couple of things to check here:

- Does the profile of the user executing the code have write access to the ProfileId field?
- Does the profile of the user executing the code have the appropriate permissions, either *[Manage Internal Users](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=adding_new_users.htm&language=en_US)* for all of the internal license types, or *[Manage External Users or Edit Self-Service Users](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_create_external_users.htm)* for Partner and Customer Community users?
- Is the user executing the code a [Delegated User Administrator](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=delegating_user_administration.htm&language=en_US), and does the profile being assigned have the *Modify All Data* permission, which is not permitted?
- Does the user executing the code have the *[View Setup and Configuration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50824/invalid-field-username-on-user-soql-query)* permission?